# curl to the "kubernetes cluster node service" fails intermittently from master node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a cluster with one master and 2 nodes.

I have deployed a nginx service on the node1 and node2 using replicas 4 from the master

I have created a 'NodePort' Service as below to make the nginx services running on node1 (2 pods) and node2 (2 pods) accessible from outside the network.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    type: nginx-service
    name: nginx-web-application

spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30006
  selector:
      app: nginx
```

**From** each of the node (node1 and node2), if i curl the pods (pod1 and pod2) to the port 80, nginx is accessible.

After creation of above Service , I am trying to curl to the nginx service from master to the node1 and node2.

```
curl http://<ip of node1>:30006
curl http://<ip of node1>:30006
```

both commands are intermittently successful, means 2 times success, 3 times failure, 3 times success, 1 time failure....so on.

I have these three centos machines in a single network created via vagrant machine. these three machines are reachable over the internet, as well as they are reachable to each other.

As there are 2 nodes and each node having 2 pods, the connection to the nginx application should be persistent (it shouldnt be intermittant)

Below commands to access the nginx from the master machine should be reachable all the time. Please guide what is missing

```
curl http://<ip of node1>:30006
curl http://<ip of node1>:30006
```

Comment: What is your centos, Kubernets version and what kind of overlay network?

Comment: centos: CentOS Linux 7 (Core),  kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}, 
Finally network is flannel

Comment: I can't reproduce (Debian). Please verify [requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl) --pod-network-cidr during initialization, `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` While using Vagrant it creates two interfaces first it can be public)  `By default, flannel selects the first interface on a host verify you network interfaces it can lead to problems with flannel network` [here](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html#firewalls)  Please let us know if it helped.

Comment: `node2.vm.network "private_network"` I am using private network, for all three servers, besides while initialization i have used `--pod-network-cidr` properly to make it use cidr block in which my nodes are created currently. as i mentioned earlier, the nodes and master are able to ping each other and they are in one network, even internet is reachable from each of the node and master, but it looks like this issue related with application, rather than the network, but I might be wrong either.

Comment: It's strange it looks like your service is scrapping f.e. different pods. Please provide `kubectl get deploy,pods,svc,ep,nodes -o wide`